# Unable to align HTML tables parallel to each other

Tags: html, css, datagrid

I have created two HTML grid tables but I am finding difficulty while placing/aligning them parallel to each other.

I am using align = right but the table is getting aligned downwards(one below the other) and not shifting to right in parallel order . Can anyone suggest where I am making mistake in my below code and how can I rectify it?

**P.S**: My below code issue can be checked by copying and saving it in a notepad say test.txt and renaming it as test.html and open it in IE or Firefox browser.

```
<table id="ss" class="easyui-datagrid" style="width:380px;height:auto;">
  <thead>
    <tr><th field="name2" width="80">Status</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr> <td>India</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Canada</td></tr>
    <tr><td>USA</td></tr>
    <tr><td>UK</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table id="vv" class="easyui-datagrid" style="width:380px;height:auto;" align = "right">
  <thead>
    <tr><th field="name3" width="80">Status</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>India</td></tr>
    <tr><td>China</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Oz</td></tr>
    <tr><td>UK</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Having 2 closing body tags and no opening body tag won't help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your solution:

```
    <div style="float:left;"><table id="ss" class="easyui-datagrid" style="width:380px;height:auto;">
  <thead>
    <tr><th field="name2" width="80">Status</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr> <td>India</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Canada</td></tr>
    <tr><td>USA</td></tr>
    <tr><td>UK</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div style="float:left;"><table id="vv" class="easyui-datagrid" style="width:380px;height:auto;">
  <thead>
    <tr><th field="name3" width="80">Status</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>India</td></tr>
    <tr><td>China</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Oz</td></tr>
    <tr><td>UK</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer is working and it is aligning right but it is creating two tables attached to each other. I want to add some distance of separation between them for a better look and feet. How can I add space between two tables?

Comment: For that you can give margin-left:50px; to second div.

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want the tables side by side rather than one below the other?

You can either add a `float: left` to the first table (and not forget to clear after the second table), or put each of the tables in a `div` and set `display: inline-block` on those `div`s.

Comment: Yes I want to create tables side by side and with some space of separation between them for a better look and feel. Can you please elaborate on the approach you have suggested?

Answer (score 0):

```
jsfiddle.net/S45CQ/
```

use float:left property and either reduce width of the table or put them in a wrapper div.

Also remove two closing body tag from your html.

Answer (score 0):

The align right style on a table will align all elements inside to the right. (text and images etc in each column).

You need to add "float:left;" in the style.

Answer (score 0):

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/TmC4C/

You also need to specify `align="left"` on your first table. Although you are much better off using [floats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) instead.

I have changed your widths to `50%`, as it could also be the widths of the tables are too large for the screen size, causing one to push the other below it.